# Evaluating a path (contour) integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I want to evaluate this contour integral:

$\int_{\gamma}e^{\frac{-1}{z}}dz$ where $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$ on $[0,2\pi]$

I have tried several methods. The first one I tried is direct parameterization:

First, I write $z$ with respect to $\gamma(z)$:

$\int_{\gamma}e^{\frac{-1}{e^{it}}}\frac{dz}{dt}dt$

I then calculate $\frac{dz}{dt}$:

$\frac{d(e^{it})}{dt}=ie^{it}$

Replacing and rearranging I get:

$\int e^{\frac{-1}{e^{it}}}ie^{it}dt$

and from here... I am stuck.

I tried to apply the generalization of the fundamental theorem of calculus, but in order to find a "clean" antiderivative I need to use the exponential integral Ei and it seems awfully complicated and messy.

Any ideas or suggestions ? 
Are my steps right?

Comment: Residues${}{}$?

Comment: ouh totally forgot about that! I'm going to try it right away.

Comment: I am having some difficulties with residues. Specifically, I can't find the poles. Help?

Comment: There are no poles; there is an essential singularity.

Comment: oh... I see. Unfortunately, I don't know how to deal with essential singularities. Any other suggestions to calculate the integral ?

Answer (score 1):

$\exp(-1/z)$ has the Laurent series
$$\exp(-1/z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!z^n}.$$
The residue at the origin is the coefficient of $1/z$, that is $-1$.
Thus
$$\int_\gamma \exp(-1/z)\,dx=-2\pi i.$$

Comment: I know that the residue is the coefficient $a_{-1}$ of the Laurent series. But your sum starts from 0. How are you deducing that it is -1? Sorry, I am sure it's supposed to be evident, but I am confused...

Comment: @jkbestami When n=1, you get a $z^{-1}$ term.